# MongoDB / MongoChef User and roles not working?

Tags: mongodb, permissions, unauthorized

I have installed mongodb (version 3.0.7) on Mac / localhost, 
everything seems to work fine; 
 - I can start the mongodb server , 
 - access the databases, create them, add users,..
 - created a userAdminAnyDatabase in the admin database and add the next lines to the mongo.conf file : 
  auth:true
  setParameter:enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
(I also tried different notation etc. but nothing seems to work out)

Strange thing and the problem is that when I am using Mongochef, 
where I also successfully created users and can view the users I add throughout the terminal, there seems no difference between users with 'read-only' and Admin rights? So when I login with a read-only account : I can view all databases and also edit them / add them ; add users etc. 
+
I am also still able to login without credentials (which if I am right may not be possible anymore after executing previous steps?)

I just can't find a way to configure it with permissions and prevent unauthorized access to my Mongodb databases. Would be great if someone can help me, searching for days right now and nothing seems to help. Thank you! : )

Comment: Do you have any source code to post?

Comment: Firstly I had installed mongoDB when creating a REST API in Python using Bottle and MongoDB: 

1
sudo mkdir -m 777 -p /data/db
Download MongoDB:

wget http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.6.5.tgz
tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.6.5.tgz
Now let’s start MongoDB:

cd mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.6.5/bin
./mongod

everything worked fine; I was able to get, put,.. to the API and store in the mongoDB. But unfortunately that installation hadn't a mongod.conf file, so I also installed mongoDB with home-brew

Comment: With above configuration, I do the following in terminal when starting up: 
- ./mongod     
- mongo mydatabase
=> I am able to read it, see the users,.. (with db.documents.find()) which works OK

I also can connect to mongoDB with mongochef 
using localhost on port 27017 and without authentication; but I just don't get it why I am able to do it without the authentication. I have set up the adminanydatabase in the admin database and used the auth:true setParameter:enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0  but it is still possible to access it without any credentials :-(